# What to say if you don't want anything from a store?

Tags: expressions, american-english

I learned English as a second language. As I have never lived in any English speaking country, sometimes I don't know what to say in common daily situations.

One good example of this occurred when I stayed in US for three weeks, beginning of this year. Sometimes I went to a store, was asked what I was looking for, but I didn't know the best way to answer as I wasn't looking for anything specific, just taking a look.

What could I say in this situations, when you don't want the crew's assistance or are not looking for something in particular?

Thanks,

Comment: In US, *Just looking* is fine. Or *Nothing in particular.*

Comment: Yeah, "Just lookin'" is what I'll say 9 times out of ten.  If the person has shown particular interest I first smile and then say "No thanks" or "Thank you", followed by a better enunciated "I'm just looking around."  (I'll admit that some shop people will regard foreigners (and guys with beards) with suspicion, but the way to handle that is to behave in a perfectly normal fashion.)

Comment: If you want to improve your English you can start by capitalizing the word *English*.

Comment: In the UK it's common to dismiss the salesperson with *[I'm] just **browsing** [thank you]*.

Comment: I consider this question to be too broad for English.SE, but it might be a good question for [ell.se].

Comment: Ah, ok. So the word is browsing rather than watching. Thanks, @FumbleFingers.

Comment: "I'm only looking, thanks" is also a possibility.

Comment: @200_success I originally put it there, but from my previous experience it seems to me that the community here is bigger and you get more answers and more discussion. If anything, I will move it to ELL.

Comment: "Bigger community" is not an excuse for posting to the wrong place. If everyone thinks like that, then ELL will never prosper.

Comment: What @200_success said. I would have *answered* on ELL, but I think a question like this doesn't justify more than a comment and closevote on ELU. It's really just "clutter".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I wish there was a button "Move to ELL"  on ELU :) No irony, btw. And I also think that questions here, not only like this but, in general (if not stupid) justify more than that, for us - those who just want to learn English, either on ELL or ELU.

Comment: @Arman McHitaryan: I think we won't get that button until ELL graduates out of beta mode. I also think that process is being held back by attitudes like OP's here, and by those who encourage it by upvoting/answering such misplaced questions.

Comment: Arman, in this particular case I suspect all you wanted was for someone to jog your memory with ***browsing***. But the mere fact that you came out with ***watching*** rather than the equally standard *"Just **looking**, thanks!"* suggests you would have benefited from asking on ELL (where it's practically certain someone would have explained the usage differences revolving around ***looking/watching***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Now I'm happy :) I promise more and 'more appropriate' questions on ELL from me. Peace :)

Comment: @Arman: I'm not irritated by you on a personal level. Of course most people will use any system in whatever way suits their purpose (and I think you *did* get what you wanted here quite quickly). The problem is *our* end (we, the userbase collectively), in that we don't have a proper mechanism for clarifying and maintaining the distinction between the two sites. But I hope you'll persevere with ELL - especially if you want answers targeted at helping you learn broader principles of language use, rather than simple *this is one of the things native speakers say* answers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, this is little bit off topic, anyway. My whole point was that if anybody finds the question should be moved to ELL then there's absolutely no point to say that in offensive way. It was not just the word observe/look that I forgot and wanted somebody to remind me. This is honest. Btw, I have already posted questions on ELL and many more than on ELU. Wish everybody good night.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I'm just browsing, thanks" would be a good response in England or Australia.

Comment: We use that in the US also.

Answer (score 7):

There are so many options for this:

> Clerk: *Can I help you find anything?*
>
> You:
>
> - *No thanks, I'm doing fine.*
> - *I'm good.*
>
>   - This is very informal but very natural for a native speaker. Depending on *how* you say it, it can also come off a bit tersely.
> - *I'm just looking/browsing, thanks.*
>
>   - "Browsing" is a great word for when you're not necessarily planning to buy anything
> - *Not right now, I'll let you know if I need anything.*
>
>   - This is a great way to imply gently that you'd rather they not bother you. It may be too subtle for some shopkeepers but it's usually understood as a polite way to ask to be left to your own devices.

Comment: +1, Nice edit. Those are probably the most common replies, along with the simple "no thank you".

Comment: @crosscounter I tried to look up visual minority, and still don't know what it means.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the comment in the first place. thanks for your combined answer post

Comment: "I'm good" is very natural for *younger* native speakers, IMO.  No one is asking "*how* are you?", they're asking if you need help finding something.  "No, thank you" or "I'm just browsing" are sufficient.  Sorry for the rant but this and "No problem" instead of "you're welcome" as a response to "Thank you" are a pet peeve of mine! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez "I'm good" in this case means "I don't need help", not "I'm well".

Comment: No...it doesn't mean "I don't need help,"  that's my point.  It's used in that scenario but doesn't actually mean that.  Such is our ever-changing language! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez If it's used that way, it means that. That's how the "ever-changing language" works.

Comment: Not literally. :-p

Answer (score 2):

The answers can change according to context as well as how the clerk approaches you, but these work in most cases:

1. I am fine. & I am good. or I got it/(I think) I will be ok.
2. Just browsing.

Keep in mind that your body gesture is important too. (crossed arms/open palms to resist the approach is a clear sign that you don't want to be bothered)

Edit: I lived in Toronto, ON Canada for 10 years.

Comment: +1, "I'm good" is the first thing that comes to mind for me, but I would expect 'looking' rather than 'browsing' (US)

Comment: @DCShannon
`Looking` is definitely out there - I felt that browsing is more "formal" and universal. I would be more inclined to say 'looking' in most cases.

Comment: "I'm good" is very idiomatic but it may seem a bit odd coming from a non-native speaker? It was my first thought, too, to be honest.

Comment: @Catija I believe the asker/OP specifically wanted "what natives use"

Answer (score 0):

- You could also say "**I'm just scouting around**".

But it wouldn't be wrong if you answered: "I'm just looking, thank you."

> - "scout around" (phrasal verb) look in different places for something
> - "We scouted around to find the best price." [UE.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/scout+around.html)

Comment: I think *scouting around* would be a little unusual in AmE. *Scouting around for what?* would be my immediate response as a retail worker. *I'm just looking* or *I'm just browsing* or *I'm just having a look* are rather more noncommittal.

Answer (score 0):

> Window shopping

Oh, are you buying something expensive? No, I'm just window shopping.

Comment: Technically, "window shopping" is done outside of stores, looking in the display windows.